# Python3 Type System: Call for a specific attribute in argument?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

Suppose I have a function I want to create for a set of objects that are all different, from different libraries, but which have the same process attribute:

```
def get_foo(fooable, fooer):
  return fooer.foo(fooable)
```

This is a useful function in any OOP language that allows one to define a particular interface that an object must support...

In python's type hinting system, is it possible for me to declare that the function will fail if `fooer` does not have attribute `foo`?

```
# in psuedo code
def get_foo(fooable, fooer: Type.has_attr('foo')):
   return fooer.foo(fooable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python natively defines things that act like interfaces, in [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). This is implemented [by using ABC metaclasses, specifically defining the `__instancecheck__()` and/or `__subclasscheck__()` methods on a metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks). You could do something similar: define an Abstract Base Metaclass that acts like an interface:

```
>>> class FooableMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
...     def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
...         return (
...             hasattr(instance, 'foo')            # has a .foo
...             and callable(instance.foo)          # .foo is callable
...             and not isinstance(instance, type)  # is an instance, not a class
...         )
... 
>>> class Fooer(metaclass=FooableMeta):
...     def __init__():
...         raise NotImplementedError()
...     def foo():
...         raise NotImplementedError()
... 
>>> class Foo:
...     def foo():
...         print("foo")
... 
>>> isinstance(Foo(), Fooable)
True
>>> class Bar:
...     def bar():
...         print("bar")
... 
>>> isinstance(Bar(), Fooable)
False
```

You can now use `Fooable` for type hinting, by the same principle.